# SQL server query xml attribute closing on each field

Tags: sql-server, sqlxml

I need to write a Sql server query to generate exactly this xml file.

```
<Ob name="MData">
  <FieldList>
    <Field name="ID">0980</Field>
    <Field name="IDDes">Working</Field>
    <Field name="Category">Arts Student</Field>
  </FieldList>
</Ob>
```

My table looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[MData](
  [ID] [nvarchar](50) NULL, 
  [IDDes] [nvarchar](50) NULL, 
  [Category] [nvarchar](50) NULL)
```

This is what I did so far, but I need some experts help to get the exact XML format.

```
Select ( 
    Select 
        'ID' as '@name',
        ID 
    from 
        dbo.MData as B 
    Where A.ID = B.ID 
    FOR XML Path('Field'), Type 
), ( 
    Select 
        'IDDes' as '@name' , 
        IDDes 
        From dbo.MData As B 
    Where A.ID = B.ID 
    FOR XML Path('Field'), Type 
), ( 
    Select 
        'Category' as '@name' , 
        category 
    From dbo.MData As B 
    Where A.ID = B.ID 
    FOR XML Path('Field'), Type 
) 
FROM dbo.MData As A 
FOR XML path('FieldList'), Root('OB')
```

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a "give me the codes" site; we expect you to put some effort in first, and show what you have tried.  Furthermore, you make no mention of the table schemas, although I can guess what it is.

Comment: What base table do you want to get your data from? Please show us the table structure and sample data!

Comment: CREATE TABLE [dbo].[MData](
 [ID] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
 [IDDes] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
 [Category] [nvarchar](50) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

Comment: ID IDDes Category
0980 Working Arts Student
0981 Working Arts Student
070 Not Working Arts Student

Comment: Select  (  Select 'ID' as '@name',ID 
          from dbo.MData  as B Where A.ID = B.ID
            FOR XML Path('Field'), Type ), 
            (  Select 'IDDes:' as '@name' , IDDes 
            From dbo.MData As B Where A.ID = B.ID
            FOR XML Path('Field'), Type ),     
        (  Select 'Category:' as '@name' , category 
            From dbo.MData As B Where A.ID = B.ID
            FOR XML Path('Field'), Type )
  FROM dbo.MData As A
  FOR XML path('FieldList'), Root('OB')

Comment: This is what I did so far I need some expert help to get the exact XML format. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is your select...

```
Select ( 
    Select 
        'ID' as '@name',
        ID 
    from 
        dbo.MData as B 
    Where A.ID = B.ID 
    FOR XML Path('Field'), Type 
), ( 
    Select 
        'IDDes' as '@name' , 
        IDDes 
        From dbo.MData As B 
    Where A.ID = B.ID 
    FOR XML Path('Field'), Type 
), ( 
    Select 
        'Category' as '@name' , 
        category 
    From dbo.MData As B 
    Where A.ID = B.ID 
    FOR XML Path('Field'), Type 
) 
FROM dbo.MData As A 
FOR XML path('FieldList'), Root('OB')
```

Wrap each of your values with `(SELECT your_value)`.

Like this:

```
Select ( 
    Select 
        'ID' as '@name',
        (SELECT ID)
    from 
        dbo.MData as B 
    Where A.ID = B.ID 
    FOR XML Path('Field'), Type 
), ( 
    Select 
        'IDDes' as '@name' , 
        (SELECT IDDes)
        From dbo.MData As B 
    Where A.ID = B.ID 
    FOR XML Path('Field'), Type 
), ( 
    Select 
        'Category' as '@name' , 
        (SELECT category)
    From dbo.MData As B 
    Where A.ID = B.ID 
    FOR XML Path('Field'), Type 
) 
FROM dbo.MData As A 
FOR XML path('FieldList'), Root('OB')
```

Comment: Dear Ozren, thank you so much from the bottom of my heart. This is what I was looking for. Thanks again.